# How to run different instances of same java code

Tags: java, database, jsp, jms

I have a JSP page from which I want to call different independent instances of same java code. In the JSP, the user has the option to select and run multiple analyses(on call records) and each analysis uses the same java code as its business logic, So I am looking for the best technique to implement this.Will API like JMS be useful ? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Java has this concept called "objects", where you instantiate classes and create stateful objects.

Comment: Do you just want to run the same code for multiple instances, or do you want to run them parallely?

Comment: @anirudh I want to run the same code multiple times with a single request either parallely or sequentially.

Comment: what do you mean by a single request?

Comment: @anirudh what i mean is that, with a single "Submit" button press i want to call multiple instances of my java code corresponding to different analyses selected by the user, in JSP.

Answer (score 0):

As Smutje said:

Put the reusable code in a separate class.
Loop through the list of analyses(I don't know what they are) and create an object for the class for each iteration and call any method inside the class with the required arguments.